# Update of R elastic package results in Send failure: Broken pipe

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I updated the elastic package from 0.8.7 to 1.1.0 and now I get an error even though I didn't change anything in my code. The affected function is **docs_bulk**. I read something about the size of the data I try to upload, but the size doesn't matter, as I already tried to upload a data frame with only one row. If I downgrade the R package, everything works fine. However, I want to use the new R package. What can I do?

**Session Info**

R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] elastic_1.1.0

**Elasticsearch**

> curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200'
> {
> "name" : "XYZ",
> "cluster_name" : "XYZ",
> "cluster_uuid" : "0wNT8jgiTryABUoz8hLAfw",
> "version" : {
> "number" : "7.2.0",
> "build_flavor" : "default",
> "build_type" : "rpm",
> "build_hash" : "508c38a",
> "build_date" : "2019-06-20T15:54:18.811730Z",
> "build_snapshot" : false,
> "lucene_version" : "8.0.0",
> "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
> "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
> },
> "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"

**R Code**

```
es_conn <- elastic::connect(host = es_host, port = es_port, errors = "complete")
elastic::docs_bulk(conn = es_conn, x = df_com, index = es_idx)
```

This results in the following error:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(x$url$url, handle = x$url$handle) :
> Send failure: Broken pipe

Comment: You might want to report the issue there: https://github.com/alexioannides/elasticsearchr/issues